# Print a multiplication table using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

When I try to print a multiplication table using the following code,

```
    Dim se As String
    Label1.Text = Space(35) & "九九乘法表" & vbCrLf
    Label1.Text &= Space(35) & "-----------" & vbCrLf
    For i = 1 To 9
        Label1.Text &= Space(8 * (i - 1) + i)
        For j = i To 9
            se = i & "×" & j & "=" & i * j
            Label1.Text &= se & Space(8 - Len(se))
        Next j
        Label1.Text &= vbCrLf
    Next i
```

it gives me a well-aligned table as I want as the picture below

[image]

If I change the `Label1.Text &= Space(8 * (i - 1) + i)` in line 5

into `Label1.Text &= Space(8 * (i - 1) )` , the table turns out to be like this:

[image]

I guess my question will be: Why I have to add "i" spaces more?

Thanks Edper for his answer.

But I'm just confused why such an additional incrementing space is necessary?

Let's say I'm using  `Label1.Text &= Space(8 * (i - 1) )` , then there will be no space in the 1st loop, 8 spaces in the 2nd loop, 16 spaces in the 3rd loop... , why won't that make all the equations align?

More specifically, after the equation 1x1=1, there are 3 spaces, so right before 1x2=2, there are 8 characters, then if I have 8 spaces in the 2nd loop, 2x2=4 should have aligned with 1x2=2, but it didn't. That's what I'm wondering about.

Comment: 52Dora, that's okay, some helpful bod like myself can always do the images for you until you gather the necessary rep.

Comment: The proper way would be to use [Graphics.DrawString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Graphics.MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring.aspx). You could then use any font and have everything perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What font did you use for the Label1 control? From the screen capture, I can see that you are not using a fixed-width font.

If you change the font to fixed-width font family (eg: Courier New) you will get a perfectly aligned table with the code `Label1.Text &= Space(8 * (i - 1))`, while with `...) + i)` code will give you a table with unaligned columns.

The reason for this is, fixed-width fonts have the same width for every characters in the set,  at any font size. This include the space (Chr(32)) too. While non fixed-width fonts, each character have different width. Eg: the letter **W** is wider than **i**. And spaces will have different width too.

For example:

Fixed-width font:

```
1x1=1...1x2=2  
........2x2=4
```

Non fixed-width font:

1x1=1...1x2=2
   ........2x2=4

You can see above, in both 'table' above, I put 7 dots to push the second row to align to the second column of the first row. And in the table using non fixed-width font, the `2x2=4` appears to the left to where it should be.

That means, since the space is narrower, you need to append more spaces to make it aligned like below:

1x1=1...1x2=2
   .............2x2=4

In the sample table above, I have to put in **13** dots to make it appear aligned (or close enough). Since this page is using some other font to display this table.

In your case, you are just lucky enough that the font you are using can be aligned perfectly by simply adding `i`.

Comment: I think you're answer is more accurate than mine. I give you my upvote that you truly deserve. GOD bless.

Comment: That's a perfect answer! In my case, I'm using a Chinese font called "宋体", and I believe while I was lucky enough to add an "i", I'm more lucky to receive your answer.  ( ^_^ )  Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks @Edper for the upvote, and thanks 52Dora for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

Your `i` variable here add an incrementing space every loop

```
Label1.Text &= Space(8 * (i - 1) + i)
```

So, to remove the `i` variable then would remove that additional incrementing space every loop

```
Label1.Text &= Space(8 * (i - 1))
```

Let's analyze the 2x2 for example using the formula `Space(8 * (i - 1) + i)` would give
you 8*(2-1)+2 or 10 spaces

Now using the formula `Space(8 * (i - 1))` would give you 8*(2-1) or 8 spaces.

So, that would explain the difference in spacing in your output and the rugged looking or non-aligning of your multiplication table on the second one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But that's still not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, hopefully I've got the what-I-want answer, although I cannot fully understand it now. Maybe I'll have to give up my supper and figure it out. Thanks again and best reguards~